# The set of invertible elements of a monoid is closed under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, monoid

Let $M$ be a monoid and let $U(M)$ be the set of invertible elements of $M$. How can I prove that $U(M)$ is closed under the binary operation on $M$, i.e., that that $a \in U(M)$ and $b \in U(M)$ implies that $ab \in U(M)$?

Comment: Is $U$ the binary operation on $M$?

Comment: M is a Monoid and U(M) is the set of elements in M that are invertible.

Comment: Thus, you hav to prove that, if $a$ and $b$ are *invertible*, also $ab$ is.

Comment: You have to exploit the definition of [invertible element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Properties) of a monoid.

Comment: yes i know this but still cant see how it works

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: if $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $a$ and $b^{-1}$ is the inverse of $b$, compute $(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1})$ and $(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab)$. What can you conclude?

Comment: That (ab) has an inverse!